# Installing Swish++ from the source code

Tags: software-installation

I'm a linux beginner, so forgive me for such a stupid question.

I have Ubuntu 12.04, and I need to install Swish++ on it, the C++ version. 
I can't use

```
apt-get install swish++
```

as it installs Perl version, and moreover I must use the source code only (I need it for my graduation work). 
I've downloaded the archive from the official page of Swish++ (http://swishplusplus.sourceforge.net).
I read the Install file, changed headers as it was written and i have no idea of what i should do after it. Where should I run "make" command? It will be perfect if someone has a step-by-step instruction for it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, please note that the software you want to build is **old**. It's known to give problems on recent installations. Eg. [Debian bug #417712](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=417712).

1. Make sure you've installed basic build environment packages (compiler, etc.): [build-essential [image: Install build-essential]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/build-essential)
2. Download and unpack the source in some directory. Let's do this in one go, using `wget` and `tar` using a pipe. (This is just one way to do it.)

   ```
   wget -O - http://downloads.sourceforge.net/swishplusplus/swish%2B%2B-6.1.5.tar.gz \
   | tar -zxvf -
   ```
3. Change into that directory

   ```
   cd swish++-6.1.5/
   ```
4. Read the Install readme for Unix operating systems.

   ```
   less INSTALL.unix
   ```

   - Prerequisites are covered in our first step.
   - "Building SWISH++ for Unix" part includes some steps which are based on your preference. I can't provide that here. Without actually following these steps you'll run into errors like:

     > error: #error You have not set TempDirectory_Default for your system.

     Don't forget to follow the instructions like

     > Comment out these lines after you have set it.
5. Run `make` in the directory. So, yeah, just

   ```
   make
   ```

   In case your compiler gives the

   ```
   conf_var.c:259:9: error: ‘::exit’ has not been declared
   ```

   error, then follow the instructions from the Debian bug report on how to get it built.

Comment: Thank you for help! I have one more question: what TempDirectory_Default[] should I set in "config.h"? I have Ubuntu 12.04 on virtual machine (VirtualBox) and my host system is Windows 8.1. What can you say about swap space or other parameters it will influence?

Comment: @user231990 I have no clue, because I don't have knowledge about the swish++ internals/usage. I've only just tried to build it.